# Issue when I try to get an array as particular matrix case of m*1 size

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, matrix

I need to get the last column of a matrix and multiply this for another matrix(scalar product), **since I don't want to rewrite another multiply method (that receives a matrix and an array instead of two matrix)** I have tried to write this method to return last column as **m*1** matrix

```
float **getLastColumn(int m, int n, float **InputMatrix) {
    int i,j;
    float **lcm= matrix_alloc(m,1);
        for(i=0; i<m; i++) {
            lcm[i][0]=InputMatrix[i][n-1];
        }

    return lcm;
}
```

and try to get the result with

```
float **X = getLastColumn(rows, columns, someMatrix);
```

But this doesn't works, and get **segmentation fault error**.

Any suggestion how to fix this problem? Thanks.

if is relevant below there is the allocation method used

```
float **matrix_alloc(int m, int n)
{
    int i;
    float **arr = malloc(n*sizeof(*arr));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        arr[i]=malloc(m*sizeof(**arr));
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: `float **lcm= matrix_alloc(m,1);` --> `float **lcm= matrix_alloc(1,m);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition of the `for` loop in `getLastColumn()` uses the wrong variable:

```
for(i=0; j<m; i++) {
  ...
}
```

The loop should check for `i<m` instead.

Additionally the `matrix_alloc()` function seems to have its parameters in the opposite than expected order. `matrix_alloc(a,b)` allocates an array like `float[b][a]`. This doesn't match the way it is used in `getLastColumn()`, and `lcm` ends up with the wrong dimension being size 1. The allocation `matrix_alloc(a,b)` should be changed to keep the two dimensions in the expected order.

Comment: thanks, this is surely an error, but also after fix still same issue

Answer (score 2):

The `n` and `m` variables are inverted in your `matrix_alloc()` code.

Write:

```
float **matrix_alloc(int m /* rows */, int n /* columns */)
{
    int i;
    float **arr = malloc(m*sizeof(*arr));
    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        arr[i]=malloc(n*sizeof(**arr));
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest changing `m` and `n` to be `rows` and `cols` or similar , to help you avoid this sort of problem